# React video loading in memory before rendering to screen

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, html5-video, loading

I am having a hard time figuring out how to load a spinner while a video is loading. I don't want to do a DOM loader, I want everything on the page to load up while the video is loading. So far, when I use `onLoadStart` and `onLoadedData`, they both seem to fire at the same time as the entire page is done loading. Not helpful.

***Is there a way to async load this and show a spinner while loading? Perhaps load into virtual memory or something?***

Here is my current code:

*"render" function*

```
    const { isLoading } = this.state;

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {isLoading && (
                <CircularProgress />
            )}

            <video
                loop
                muted
                autoPlay
                src={WaveVideo}
                preload={'auto'}
                type={'video/mp4'}
                className={classes.video}
                ref={ref => this.headerVideo}
                onLoadStart={() => {
                    console.log('...I am loading...')
                    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
                }}
                onLoadedData={() => {
                    console.log('Data is loaded!')
                    this.setState({ isLoading: false });
                }}>
            </video>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you have the `autoplay` attribute included, using the `onplay` event ought to work for this case. I've modified your original example to demonstrate:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({isLoading: true})
}

render() {
    const { isLoading } = this.state;

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {isLoading && <CircularProgress />}

            <video
                loop
                muted
                autoPlay
                src={WaveVideo}
                preload={'auto'}
                type={'video/mp4'}
                className={classes.video}
                ref={ref => this.headerVideo}
                onCanPlayThrough={() => this.setState({isLoading: false})}>
            </video>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

So when this component is created it'll run the `componentDidMount` lifecycle function to set the initial loading indicator state, causing the spinner to render alongside the loading video. We, then, unset the loading indicator state once the video has begun playing on its own, which causes the spinner to no longer render.

EDIT:

I've since learned that the event you are binding in your example `onloadeddata` "is fired when the first frame of the media has finished loading". This neatly explains why you were seeing both events firing at once. The event you were intending to use was actually `onloadend`. I've included it in the example, above, replacing the original `onplay` handler.

Comment: Awesome, will try asap

Comment: My apologies, I forgot to include my source for the onloadeddata event documentation: https://devdocs.io/dom_events/loadeddata

Comment: onCanPlay worked for me but onLoadEnd did not

Comment: Thanks @Reno - the standard events for `HTMLMediaElement` have changed since I submitted this answer. I've edited it to reflect your comment. Also worth noting that in addition to `canplay`, as you stated, there is `canplaythrough` which fires when the browser has calculated that the media can play to the end without buffering.